# Get frontage parcels lines for polygonal parcels in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, parcel

I have a polygonal parcel layer. How I can get parcel frontage boundary?

[image]

Comment: Are these parcels topologically correct, having the same vertices where boundaries overlap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: In addition to the previous answer, you could also use [ST_ClusterDBSCAN()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
create view frontage as
select block.id, st_intersection(block.geom, boundary.geom) geom
from block
join (
select st_boundary((st_dump(st_union(geom))).geom) geom
from block) boundary
on st_intersects(block.geom, boundary.geom)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So, if your city blocks are digitized correctly, run the script:

```
WITH 
tbla AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Union(geom)) geom FROM <poly_table>)
SELECT a.number, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM <poly_table> a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Original spatial solutions...

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option: from each parcel boundary, subtract the boundaries of the adjacent parcels.

```
WITH parcels(id, geom) AS (VALUES
    ( 'a1', 'POLYGON ((10 10, 10 30, 30 30, 30 10, 10 10))'::geometry ),
    ( 'a2', 'POLYGON ((50 10, 30 10, 30 30, 50 30, 50 10))'::geometry ),
    ( 'a3', 'POLYGON ((10 50, 30 50, 30 30, 10 30, 10 50))'::geometry ),
    ( 'a4', 'POLYGON ((50 50, 50 30, 30 30, 30 50, 50 50))'::geometry )
)
SELECT p.id, 
       ST_Difference( ST_Boundary(p.geom), pp.geom ) AS geom
FROM parcels p
  JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ST_Collect(ST_Boundary(p2.geom)) AS geom
              FROM parcels p2 
              WHERE p.id <> p2.id AND ST_Intersects(p.geom, p2.geom) ) AS pp ON true;
```

One advantage of this approach is that it scales to an unlimited number of parcels.  It may also provide better feedback if the parcels are not actually noded correctly (since in this case more of each parcels linework will be kept).

Answer (score 1):

You can select your road ROW polygons and create a separate feature class of them, then dissolve them into one massive polygon. Run a 1ft buffer around the exterior of your ROW polygon layer. You now have a layer that encroaches into each parcel by 1ft. Then you run a union with whatever parcels you wish to calculate frontage for. This will cut your 1ft buffer every time it crosses into a new parcel. In an editing session you can then delete the original buffer polygon and your parcels so that you're only left with the sliver portion you want. You should be left with a layer that is tiny little slivers 1ft wide by whatever frontage each lot has. To calculate each lot's frontage, you build a new attribute field called "perimeter" and one called "frontage" in your parcel sliver layer. Using calculate geometry you can calculate the perimeter of each sliver in ft. Then since you know that each sliver is 1ft wide, you can run a field calculator formula in your "frontage" field that is =("perimeter"-2)/2 This should give you a result that is very close to true frontage of each parcel. You can remove decimals so everything is viewed as clean whole numbers. This is the method that worked for me. We use road and river frontage for market calculations in our office. [image]

This works for waterfront as well:
[image]